# How to create and manage cron jobs from web based

Tags: php, yii2, raspberry-pi3, yii2-basic-app

I need help completing my project. My project is to control the light through the website using Raspberry Pi. The lamp should be able to set the schedule when ON and OFF via website (Yii2 Framework).
And now the problem is, I do not know or understand how to create and manage the lamp lamp schedule through website (Yii2 Framework).
I need help to solve the problem.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: but how to make cron GUI can be arranged through website yii2?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [`yii2tech/crontab`](https://github.com/yii2tech/crontab) extension for this:

> ```
> use yii2tech\crontab\CronJob;
> use yii2tech\crontab\CronTab;
>
> $cronJob = new CronJob();
> $cronJob->min = '0';
> $cronJob->hour = '0';
> $cronJob->command = 'php /path/to/project/yii some-cron';
>
> $cronTab = new CronTab();
> $cronTab->setJobs([
>     $cronJob
> ]);
> $cronTab->apply();
> ```

Comment: But how can the client can schedule a lamp through the website?